# Падает kwin после запуска java приложения

Tags: java, kubuntu

После обновления в Kubuntu 15.04 появились проблемы с запуском java приложений. При их запуске падает kwin.
Проверено на LibreOffice и PhpStorm.

```
Linux 3.19.0-33-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:18:12 UTC 2015

KDE 4.14.8

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid

java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема решается на https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1512760